# Problem creating KSQL stream - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb, snappy

I'm trying to create a stream using KSQL but I'm getting an error returned.

The statement I'm running is:
create stream s1 with (kafka_topic = 'T3_NON_END', value_format = 'avro');

I get a NoClassDefFoundError - org.xerial.snappy.Snappy

From what I've read this is because /tmp is set as noexec.  It looks from the Confluent website and also from looking at other applications that use Snappy, that a directory path needs to be passed.

https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.2/ksql/docs/troubleshoot-ksql.html

Does anyone know how I can pass the directory path for Snappy when using KSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're asking how to set JVM flags

```
export KSQL_OPTS='-D...'
ksql-server-start...
```

> this is because /tmp is set as noexec.

Not necessarily. The error is saying snappy is not on the JVM classpath

Comment: That pointed us in the right direction.  
Adding KSQL_OPTS stopped the error happening in KSQL, but then caused a different error.  I had a look at server.log and that had the same NoClassDefFoundError, so I set KAFKA_OPTS and that fixed the issue and it successfully created the Stream.  
Thanks for your help on this